# What to do with this suggested edit?

Tags: discussion

I have just reached 2k, and of course I checked out the 'Suggested Edits' review queue. There was [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7794864), and I was thinking it should be rejected, because it's the original poster that should add an example. How does the editor know if this was the intent of the original poster? Maybe this edit should have been an answer of its own, but I didn't find a reject reason that would cover this.
On the other hand, it improves the answer, does that mean it's ok?

What should I do in such a situation?

Comment: Since the OP and editor have the same display name; I assume the user is playing [around with OpenIDs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61142/212576).

Comment: Yesterday, one of them was 'Fritz', the other one was 'Userxxxxxx'. But now it seems they are really the same person.

Comment: @alain They are 2 different users. Name is the same but userid is different - kind a try of post hijacking ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, yes I know they are different accounts, yesterday they had different names, so it was not obvious they could belong to the same person. But Grant suspected that this could be the case, and now it seems very likely.

Comment: Or it is another user that tries to disguise himself in the original poster ... I cannot make the difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree, that's an odd edit and should be rejected. The problem (one of the problems anyway) with adding a huge block of code like that, is that people may start asking questions about it, and the original answerer may have no clue what to say about it.

The "attempt to reply" reason applies, which is what three other people just selected to reject it:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment **or an answer.** *(my emphasis)*

Something seems odd about it. It almost seems like the user forgot their original account and re-registered under a new one. Both accounts are from today - the original 8 hours ago, and the editor 30 minutes ago. But I wouldn't know for sure, so I think the best you can do with the information available to you is just reject it.

Comment: This occured to me too: 2 accounts for the same person. Your first paragraph is a very good reason, I didn't think about that, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll use the "attempt to reply" reason too, in the future. I wasn't sure about the "intent to address the author" part.

Comment: If the edit would actually make a good answer, I use the "causes harm" custom reason to explicitly encourage the editor to post one (if they bother to check why their edit was rejected).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: So, never then. (I kid; I've checked back myself a few times. It's not easy though.)

Comment: "*adding a huge block of code like that, is that people may start asking questions about it, and the original answerer may have no clue what to say about it.*" The good thing is that you can explicitly ask the editor by replying directly to them with `@`. It won't be autocompleted, but you are able to notify the editor ([Q5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236877/when-is-a-notification-sent)). (Not saying that the suggested edit was good and should have been approved.)